# How to select duplicate records for a column having Data/NULL values in other columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL server with 2.5 M records and I want to select the unique records as in image below. Can someone help me write a select query for this?

Original table and requested data:

[image]

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `COUNT()`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, could you help me write a query as I am a beginner?

Comment: SELECT NAME, CODE, COUNTRY, COUNTRY_CODE, COUNT(*) as COUNT 
FROM SOURCE_TABLE 
GROUP BY NAME, CODE, COUNTRY, COUNTRY_CODE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT NAME,CODE,COUNTRY,COUNTRY_CODE,COUNT(1) AS [COUNT]
 FROM SourceTable
 GROUP BY NAME,CODE,COUNTRY,COUNTRY_CODE
```